# Was Ahsoka Tano one of the younglings helping Kenobi find Kamino?

Tags: star-wars, attack-of-the-clones

In *Attack of the Clones*  Obi-Wan seeks the advice of Master Yoda in finding a missing planet.  During this time Yoda is teaching a group of younglings.  One of them is a Togruta of unknown gender who looks similar to Ahsoka Tano.  Is it ever acknowleged in canon that this is her, or is it another of her species?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This was addressed by Lucasfilm's Leland Chee.

> **Q.** ***Are Ashla and Ahsoka the same character?***
>
> **LC:** *No. The ages don't match up.*
>
> <sub><sup>[Holocron continuity database questions](https://web.archive.org/web/20090116193158/http://forums.starwars.com/thread.jspa?threadID=152583&start=1755)</sup></sub>

And since she gets a name in the [Databank](https://www.starwars.com/databank/togruta), they can't possibly be the same person.

> **TOGRUTA**
>
> Native to the planet Shili, the Togruta are notable for their striped,
> horn-like montrals and head-tails. The species has spread beyond their
> homeworld to colonies such as Kiros, which was despoiled by Zygerrian
> slavers during the Clone Wars. Notable Togruta include Governor Roshti
> of Kiros and three members of the Jedi Order: **Ashla, a youngling**; the
> Jedi Master Shaak Ti; and Anakin Skywalker’s Padawan, Ahsoka Tano.

[image]

Comment: Now to add to the confusion:Ashla was Ahsokas aliás when she was in hiding post order 66

Comment: @CBredlow Ahsoka was *originally* going to be named Ashla, but her name was later changed before the "Clone Wars" TV show premiered. They brought back the name as an alias for her in the "Ahsoka" novel during her early post-Order66 hiding.